# C# - How to initialize gradient panel demo?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, graphics, gradient

I found a [web page](http://www.openwinforms.com/creating_cool_gradient_panel_gdi.html) that describes how to create a gradient panel in a WinForms application.

Does anyone know how to initialize this panel demonstration?  There is source code but no comments or examples how the code can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You build the project to get a DLL (to add as a reference), or embed the code in your project.  On your forms designer, you should see a new item in your toolbox, drag it onto your form.

It has properties for colour etc.  Is this any help?

Comment: lol I was a little curious tbh, but we are all allowed to forget the obvious once in a while :)